# How can you add dependency source code to sourceJar task output?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

If you got a multi-project gradle build. And one module depends on another.

How could you add the dependency module source code to the output jar

Now i am using this:

```
java {
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

I am new to gradle builds and i don't know any **kotlin**.

And if you have the source code of a dependency as a .jar file. Could you also add that
to the output?

So I have a project module:

dependencies:

- project module
- local .jar

**What i want:**

One .jar of the project (including other modules and dependencies) compiled code:

**project-0.5.0.jar**

..and one .jar of the source code (including other modules and dependencies)

**project-0.5.0-sources.jar**

I have all source code of dependencies stored locally as .jar files

**Edit**

My project conventions (global for all modules):

```
plugins {
`java-library`
}

java {
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

How I am currently creating the project "fat".jar with compiled code:
(inside the build script)

```
tasks.jar {
    //manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree) // OR .map { zipTree(it) }
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

I have figured out how to add a project moduleA to another moduleB output sources .jar like so (inside moduleB's build-script):

```
tasks.sourcesJar {
    from(project(":moduleA").sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
}
```

Now I need to figure out how to include source code from a dependency .jar

```
from(file("../path/dependency-1.0.0-sources.jar"))
```

This packs the .jar as it is. I need it's files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. And it was easier than i thought. Keep in mind i am using Kotlin.

(All code snippets are inside the build.gradle.kts file of the project / module you are creating the sources .jar for)

First off you need to include either the java or java-library plugin:

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
}
```

And as far as i know, also this plugin extension:

```
java {
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

This makes the sourcesJar task available (task used to create the sources jar), and you can modify it like so:

```
tasks.sourcesJar {
    from(project(":common").sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
    from(zipTree("../libs/tinylog-2.5.0/tinylog-api-2.5.0-sources.jar"))
}
```

The first line inside the brackets includes my "common" module source code to the output .jar.

The second line adds the .java files inside the tinylog sources .jar to the output .jar.